# grouping name in the same table

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following SQL table columns...

```
id | name  | under
---|-------|------
 0 | Nill  |  -1  
 1 | Name1 |   0 
 2 | Name2 |   0 
 3 | Name3 |   0  
 4 | Name4 |   1  
 5 | Name5 |   2 
 6 | Name6 |   2 
 7 | Name7 |   1  
 8 | Name8 |   3  
 9 | Name9 |   2 
 10| Name10|   3
```

and i need the output like the below

```
Name1
  Name4
  Name7
Name2
  Name5
  Name6
  Name9
Name3
  Name8
  Name9
```

Help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Explain better it's confusing, and post your code too it's easier for us to debug.

Comment: How come you want that order?

Comment: @jarlh look the under column it gaves us the position expected

Comment: @FoxCy, it does?

Comment: @jarlh I think so except for the last I think for `Name3`  it's`Name8 Name10`

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT id parent , * FROM Users WHERE under = 0
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CTE.id patent ,T.* FROM Users T INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.id = T.under 
 )
 select * from CTE 
 order by parent, under
```